# Prove that if there exists an infinite linearly independent subset E, of a vector space V, then V is infinite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hamel-basis, schauder-basis

**Def:** A Hamel Basis for V is a linearly independent subset that spans V.

**Def:** If V has a finite Hamel Basis, F, then the dimension of V is equal to the number of elements in F, if not V is infinite dimensional.

**Theorem:** If V has a finite Hamel Basis then every Hamel Basis has the same number of elements.

So far I have supposed V has a finite Hamel Basis F, and E is an infinite linearly independent subset of V, I want to prove this does not hold by contradiction.

I have shown that if E spans V, F is not a finite Hamel Basis.

I think that it now suffices to show when E does not span V, F is once again not a finite Hamel Basis.

However, I am unsure of how to prove this, any help or alternative proofs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ (infinite) and $F$ (finite) are both Hamel bases, then you can write the basis elements of $F$ using the basis elements of $E$. Each basis vector of $F$ by definition uses only finitely many elements of $E$, and since $F$ is finite, you can write all basis elements of $F$ using only finitely many elements of $E$. But $F$ is a basis, so any remaining basis element of $E$ that has not been used can be written in terms of elements of $F$, which can then be written in terms of finitely many elements of $E$, a contradiction, as the elements of $E$ are supposed to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimension of a vector space $V$ is $n < \infty$, then there are maximum $n$ linearly independent vectors. If there are infinitely many linearly indipendent vectors, then the dimension of $V$ is infinite.

Comment: This statement is equivalent to the one OP is trying to prove, so this proof doesn't work.